# Can't build the project with TorchSharp-cuda-windows

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

In my project I want to use Ml.Net to train TorchSharp based NER model using GPU. So I installed required version of Nvidia CUDA:

`nvcc --version`

> Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.66
> Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0

And currently my project is referencing this 3 packages:

> Microsoft.ML (3.0.1)

> Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp (0.21.1)

> Torchsharp-cuda-windows (0.102.2)

Though with Torchsharp-cpu (0.102.2) everything worked completely fine.
There is no particular information or error message displayed, although sometimes I get this when building project.

> Child node "2" exited prematurely. Shutting down.

I tried answer provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/343645/error-msb4166-child-node-2-exited-prematurely-shut) but it didn't work in my case.

I can provide additional data if required.